Хочу поменять дребезги мышки debounce
У меня есть 2 мышки от Raze: deathadder essential & viper mini), как мы знаем данная компания с 2013 года решила проблему с дабл кликами поставив debounce(дребезги) на 10ms. Для некоторых геймеров либо задач это очень сильно мешает и я хочу поменять это значение до 1мс.
Одно из решений которые я нашел это взять installer для драйверов и в IDA pro или dnSpy в таких программах поменять значения debounce на нужное. Но там я не нахожу эту функцию скорее всего из за неопытность.
